# Statistical test for forecast performance over multiple runs

Tags: time-series, forecasting, model-comparison, diebold-mariano-test

Lets say I have a time series, create a training and test set, and I want to compare the predictive accuracy of two models, by measuring e.g. the mean absolute error (MAE) over the test set. I know that two sets of predictions can be compared with the Diebold-Mariano (DM) test or similar.

In my case, I examine performance when a number of predictors is deleted (set at 0) from test set. My process is: I randomly sample a number of observations from the test set and set a number of predictors at 0, derive predictions for both models, and estimate the MAE. The process is repeated $N$ times, which leads to $N$ MAEs for each model. Which type of statistical test is appropriate to compare the two models? Is it valid to take the raw losses over the $N$ modified test sets and apply a DM test?

Comment: What do you mean by *I modify the test set with missing values*? Are the $N$ experiments independent and carried out on independent sets of data? Given that the input to the DM test should be raw losses rather than mean losses such as MAE, what do you mean by *directly apply DM over for the predictions over all the iterations*? Consider editing your post to address these questions.

Comment: Since the $N$ cases are dependent, it may hard to derive the distribution of any test statistic under the null of equal expected loss. Also, I am curious about the rationale of replacing some predictors with zeros. What is that supposed to represent?

Comment: In each case I start from the original clean test set, aren't the $N$ case considered independent? I examine the case when a subset of predictors used for model training is unavailable in an operational setting. For example, you receive sensor measurements but there is network latency.

Comment: The cases are highly dependent because they use the exact same observations, namely the exact same target variable (though partly different predictor variables). Effectively your sample size is the size of the test set $n_{test}$, even though you reuse it $N$ times. (Though naively one could think the sample size is $N\times n_{test}$.) Since Diebold-Mariano test is basically just a $t$-test, you could perhaps formulate it as such but use $n_{test}$ as the sample size. I would still have to think a bit more about the dependence.